# Как правильно делать многоязычный сайт?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Собираюсь писать сайт на реакте и столкнулась с такой мыслью.
Раньше все время делала самым тривиальным способом - делала разные страницы и всё. Сейчас решила заняться этим вопросом и узнать как это делают остальные, как делать это правильно и лучше. Как вообще правильно делать многоязычный сайт? Какие для этого используются методы, библиотеки?

Comment: выносят строки текста в специальные словари (ru-RU, en-US и т.п.) и подключают в зависимости от нужного языка и обращаются через них (посмотрите i18n). Если контент отдает бэкенд, то соответственно там тоже должны данные храниться в соответствующих языках.

Comment: @Vein, т.е сейчас мне по-хорошему надо изучить данный метод и в частности библиотеку i18n, я правильно поняла?

Comment: Для вас добавляется еще одна глобальная переменная `language`. По сути вы должны сделать три основные вещи. Разделить весь статический контент (картинки и статические тексты) на общий и локализированный. В бекэнде в зависимости от переменной выше - подставлять нужное. Структура базы данных также делится для хранения общего контента и локализированного. И последнее структура сайта: при переключении языка должна открываться та-же страница, но на другом языке.